# Getting selected (highlighted) html from the Visual Editor on Edit Post page?

Tags: plugins, tinymce, visual-editor, syntax-highlighting

So I understand that the visual editor uses something called TinyMCE. How do I retrieve the html that the user selects from the visual editor? I am basically trying to create a button that gets the selected html and replaces it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visual editor (TinyMCE) has its own API and since its a JavaScript Based editor you can get the selection using JavaScript very easily

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
```

Comment: And just for ppl to note, you can replace the selected content using tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent('<div>sample content</div>');

Comment: So, you could use this as a replacement to `send_to_editor`, could you not?